# Function to created 100 ggplots (line) with different titles and file names to save to a folder

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have R code to create 100 individual line plots (2 lines per plot, and 100 such plots, for 100 patients) using the package ggplot2 and function `ggplot`. I am not sure how to atomize the code so that each plot will be created with filename = patient number, title on each plot=patient number and these 100 plots can be saved directly to a folder.

I have tried using function to create a loop to make the graphs, and then use `ggsave` to save them. But on calling my function, nothing seems to happen. Not sure how to troubleshoot. I tried it with only 10 patients.

My data: It is the response given by 100 patients to 22 questions(on a questionnaire). There are 100 columns - one per patient, and 44 rows. The first 22 rows are for the actual response given by patient (Grp=A) and the next 22 rows are for for what the right response should have been (Grp=B).

```
#Column names = patient no.
Patno <- c("P_1", "P_2", "P_3", "P_4", "P_5" ,"P_6" ,"P_7", "P_8", "P_9", "P_10")

#The text to be printed on each plot
Plno <- c("0001", "0002", "0003", "0004", "0005", "0006", "0007", "0008", "0009", "00010") 

# create graphing function
pdf.graph <- function(df){
  for (i in Patno){
    p <- ggplot(data=df, aes_string(x="QN", y="Patno[i]", group="Grp")) +
      geom_line(aes_string(color="Grp", linetype="Grp", size="Grp")) +
      geom_point(aes_string(color="Grp"))

   p1 <- p + 
      scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "dotted")) +
      scale_color_manual(values = c('#E69F00','#999999')) +
      scale_size_manual(values = c(1.25, 1)) +
      theme_bw() +
      theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
            axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), 
            legend.position="none") +
      scale_x_continuous(name = " ", limits = c(1, 22), 
                         breaks=seq(1,22), expand = c(0, 0) ) +
      scale_y_discrete(name=" ",
                       labels = c("TRUE" = "T", "FALSE" = "F", "Don't Know" = "DK")) +
      annotate(geom = 'text', label = " Plno[i]", 
               x = -Inf, y = Inf, hjust = 0, vjust = 1) 

   # save plots as .pdf
   ggsave(plot, 
          file = paste(resullts, 'projection_graphs/county_graphs/', 
                       Plno[i], ".pdf", sep=''), 
          scale = 2)
   print(p1)
   dev.off()
  }
}

pdf.graph(df)
```

When I call the function with the dataset df, there is no error, but no o/p is produced. I would really appreciate a reply, as to how I can get around this. It is really important for me. I've tried a number of ways.

Comment: Hi Tung. Thank you - I am looking forward to being on this community to ask questions and learn R further. I will write a Reprex. Thank you.

Comment: This is what my data set looks like. P_1, P_2 etc are the patient numbers in columns. Grp has values A and B. A= Patient response to question. B= right response to question.